# why is google map iframe not working and showing the location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

this google map iframe doesn't show the
location. why?

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/place/18%C2%B045'14.7%22N+98%C2%B059'44.0%22E/@18.7540995,98.9933669,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d18.7540944!4d98.9955556&hl=es;z=14&output=embed" frameborder="0" class="frame-p" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Comment: I had same issue with `react`. check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72043797/10315704

Answer (score 2):

Google maps requires an API key to for embeded maps to be displayed.

```
<iframe>
  width="600"
  height="450"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=YOUR_API_KEY
    &q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide

You could also use a generator to create one and copy it.

https://jsfiddle.net/q10s7ysv/

Answer (score 0):

I tried to see the location of his maps and map out. there may be an error when you copy the iframe his

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d3777.987407558813!2d98.9933669!3d18.7540995!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x0!2zMTjCsDQ1JzE0LjciTiA5OMKwNTknNDQuMCJF!5e0!3m2!1sid!2s!4v1469346687955" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

demo : https://jsfiddle.net/yz4r8jzc/